# Is using a SqlCacheDependency per user a good idea?

Tags: sql-server, ado.net

I'm thinking of caching permissions for every user on our application server. Is it a good idea to use a `SqlCacheDependency` for every user?

The query would look like this

```
SELECT PermissionId, PermissionName From Permissions Where UserId = @UserId
```

That way I know if any of those records change then to purge my cache for that user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you read [how Query Notifications work](http://rusanu.com/2006/06/17/the-mysterious-notification/) you'll see why createing many dependency requests with a single query template is good practice. For a web app, which is implied by the fact that you use [`SqlCacheDependency`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.sqlcachedependency.aspx) and not [`SqlDependency`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx), what you plan to do should be OK. If you use Linq2Sql you can also try [LinqToCache](http://code.google.com/p/linqtocache/):

```
var queryUsers = from u in repository.Users 
        where u.UserId = currentUserId 
        select u;
var user= queryUsers .AsCached("Users:" + currentUserId.ToString());
```

For a fat client app it would not be OK. Not because of the query per-se, but because `SqlDependency` in general is problematic with a large number of clients connected (it blocks [a worker thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190219.aspx) per app domain connected):

> **SqlDependency** was designed to be used in ASP.NET or middle-tier
>   services where there is a relatively small number of servers having
>   dependencies active against the database. It was not designed for use
>   in client applications, where hundreds or thousands of client
>   computers would have SqlDependency objects set up for a single
>   database server.

**Updated**

Here is the same test as @usr did in his post. Full c# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using DependencyMassTest.Properties;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;

namespace DependencyMassTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static volatile int goal = 50000;
        static volatile int running = 0;
        static volatile int notified = 0;
        static int workers = 50;
        static SqlConnectionStringBuilder scsb;
        static AutoResetEvent done = new AutoResetEvent(false);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            scsb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(Settings.Default.ConnString);
            scsb.AsynchronousProcessing = true;
            scsb.Pooling = true;

            try
            {
                SqlDependency.Start(scsb.ConnectionString);

                using (var conn = new SqlConnection(scsb.ConnectionString))
                {
                    conn.Open();

                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"
if object_id('SqlDependencyTest') is not null
    drop table SqlDependencyTest

create table SqlDependencyTest (
    ID int not null identity,
    SomeValue nvarchar(400),
    primary key(ID)
)
", conn))
                    {
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < workers; ++i)
                {
                    Task.Factory.StartNew(
                        () =>
                        {
                            RunTask();
                        });
                }
                done.WaitOne();
                Console.WriteLine("All dependencies subscribed. Waiting...");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.Error.WriteLine(e);
            }
            finally
            {
                SqlDependency.Stop(scsb.ConnectionString);
            }
        }

        static void RunTask()
        {
            Random rand = new Random();
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(scsb.ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
@"select SomeValue
    from dbo.SqlDependencyTest
    where ID = @id", conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", rand.Next(50000));

            SqlDependency dep = new SqlDependency(cmd);
            dep.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler((ob, qnArgs) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Notified {3}: Info:{0}, Source:{1}, Type:{2}", qnArgs.Info, qnArgs.Source, qnArgs.Type, Interlocked.Increment(ref notified));
            });

            cmd.BeginExecuteReader(
                (ar) =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        int crt = Interlocked.Increment(ref running);
                        if (crt % 1000 == 0)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("{0} running...", crt);
                        }
                        using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.EndExecuteReader(ar))
                        {
                            while (rdr.Read())
                            {
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Console.Error.WriteLine(e.Message);
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        conn.Close();
                        int left = Interlocked.Decrement(ref goal);

                        if (0 == left)
                        {
                            done.Set();
                        }
                        else if (left > 0)
                        {
                            RunTask();
                        }
                    }
                }, null);

        }

    }
}
```

After 50k subscriptions are set up (takes about 5 min), here are the stats io of a single insert:

```
set statistics time on
insert into Test..SqlDependencyTest (SomeValue) values ('Foo');

SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 16 ms,  elapsed time = 16 ms.
```

Inserting 1000 rows takes about 7 seconds, which includes firing several hundred notifications. CPU utilization is about 11%. All this is on my T420s ThinkPad.

```
set nocount on;
go

begin transaction
go
insert into Test..SqlDependencyTest (SomeValue) values ('Foo');
go 1000

commit
go
```

Comment: i'm afraid that caching all of that user data even for disconnected users might be too much, any alternatives?

Comment: SqlCacheDependency has cache eviction policies.

Comment: This is basically the same performance result my test has shown. Your dependency creation is multithreaded so it is faster. Probably by a factor of 4? 7s for 1000 inserts are *terrible*. 11% cpu = 1 core at 100%.

Answer (score 0):

the documentation says:

> SqlDependency was designed to be used in ASP.NET or middle-tier
>   services where there is a relatively small number of servers having
>   dependencies active against the database. It was not designed for use
>   in client applications, **where hundreds or thousands of client**
>   computers would have SqlDependency objects set up for a single
>   database server.

It tells us not to open thousands of cache dependencies. That is likely to cause resource problems on the SQL Server.

There are a few alternatives:

1. Have a dependency per table
2. Have 100 dependencies per table, one for every percent of rows. This should be an acceptable number for SQL Server yet you only need to invalidate 1% of the cache.
3. Have a trigger output the ID of all changes rows into a logging table. Create a dependency on that table and read the IDs. This will tell you exactly which rows have changed.

In order to find out if SqlDependency is suitable for mass usage I did a benchmark:

```
        static void SqlDependencyMassTest()
        {
            var connectionString = "Data Source=(local); Initial Catalog=Test; Integrated Security=true;";
            using (var dependencyConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                dependencyConnection.EnsureIsOpen();

                dependencyConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(@"
if object_id('SqlDependencyTest') is not null
    drop table SqlDependencyTest

create table SqlDependencyTest (
    ID int not null identity,
    SomeValue nvarchar(400),
    primary key(ID)
)

--ALTER DATABASE Test SET ENABLE_BROKER with rollback immediate
");

                SqlDependency.Start(connectionString);

                for (int i = 0; i < 1000 * 1000; i++)
                {
                    using (var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("select ID from dbo.SqlDependencyTest where ID = @id", dependencyConnection))
                    {
                        sqlCommand.AddCommandParameters(new { id = StaticRandom.ThreadLocal.GetInt32() });
                        CreateSqlDependency(sqlCommand, args =>
                            {
                            });
                    }

                    if (i % 1000 == 0)
                        Console.WriteLine(i);
                }
            }
        }
```

You can see the amount of dependencies created scroll through the console. It gets slow very quickly. I did not do a formal measurement because it was not necessary to prove the point.

Also, the execution plan for a simple insert into the table shows 99% of the cost being associated with maintaining the 50k dependencies.

Conclusion: Does not work at all for production use. After 30min I have 55k dependencies created. Machine at 100% CPU all the time.

Comment: hundreds of dependencies != hundreds of *computers*

Comment: I still think that every dependency has a permanent memory cost on the shared SQL Server. Probably not a good idea to open many of them.

Comment: Read http://rusanu.com/2006/06/17/the-mysterious-notification/. I know exactly how QN worsk and I'm telling you: go ahead, open many instances of the same query template, with different parameters. Is OK.

Comment: I just benchmarked this. The first 1000 dependencies took 1s. After having inserted 50k the next 1k took a minute or so. SQL Server at 100% CPU all the time. This is not what dependencies are made for!

Comment: 'benchmark' *what*? Publish your code, methodology and the measured results.

Comment: I just published the benchmark and results. You can't execute the code directly because it is using some helper methods but nothing interesting is missing.

Comment: You're measuring the cost of *setting up* the dependencies. A realistic workload does not start by creating 50k dependencies. benchmark a realistic workload. Since I know for a fact of real world cases that use exactaly this pattern and handle 8000 logins/second under spike load, I know it works. 'Benchmarking' is a complicated art. Measuring a skewed workload consisting of a single call and concluding 'it does not work' is not professional. Mix subscription, querying from cache, invalidation, in a real use case workload pattern.

Comment: The OP tries to use a dependency per user. After 100k users have been active, adding a new dependency must take a second or so. Every DML on the table becomes literally 100x more expensive. Even the most minimal incremental work possible becomes unbearably slow. What more proof do you want? **There is almost no action left that is still working quickly!** (Also, imagine this with 1M users.)

Comment: Remember, I checked the query plans for all 3 types of DML (single row modification only). Terrible plans. Literally 100x slower.